# How can you modify a cargo CSS animation to restrict movement within the screen/viewport?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm pretty new to CSS animations and I'm building a website on [Cargo](https://cargo.site/). I'm using this [preset code](https://support.cargo.site/Make-an-Image-Fly-Across-the-Screen) that helps us make images fly across the screen. I have reduced the speed and made my own modifications to that code like this -

```css
.flier {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.flier > * {
/* Adjust animation duration to change the element’s speed */
        animation: fly 200s linear infinite;
        pointer-events: none !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-120%) translateY(-120%) rotateZ(0);
    position: fixed;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    z-index: -1;
    /*z-index: 999999;*/
}


@keyframes fly {

    98.001%, 0% {
                display: block;
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    15% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }

    15.001%, 18% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-30%) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(3vh) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    40.001%, 43% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    65% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(50vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    65.001%, 68% {
        transform: translateX(20vw) translateY(-200%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }
    95% {
        transform: translateX(10vw) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }
}
```

How do I modify the code further to restrict the image movement only within my viewport so the image doesn't disappear completely when it goes off the page?

I also would like the object to be at the center of the page when the page loads/animation starts.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you want to happen to the image if it gets near the edge of your viewport. e.g. does it biunce back in some way or stop moving or....

Comment: If you view the link where the preset code is, waiting a while on the screen shows an asteroid moving on the screen. It starts somewhere outside the viewport and then moves randomly - and exists and again enters from a random location. That is the exact same thing with my object as well right now. 

I do not want it that way - I want it to start at a random location ON the screen and not fly out completely but bounce back to the edges - as in the object is always on the screen.